# ng2-bootstrap typeahead default suggestion

Tags: angular, typeahead, ng2-bootstrap

How to set the default list on focus on the typeahead field. This is my sample code below. This works fine if I type a character. but I need to show an initial list on focus. Thanks!

```
this.source = Observable
      .create((observer: any) => {
        observer.next(this.value)
      })
      .mergeMap((token: string) => {
        let params: any = {q: token}
        return this.service.search(params) //http call returns an observable
      })

<input formControlName=" [typeahead]="source">
```

Answer (score 0):

As per their [docs](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead) input `typeaheadMinLength` -
minimal no of characters that needs to be entered before typeahead kicks-in. When set to 0, typeahead shows on focus with full list of options (limited as normal by typeaheadOptionsLimit)

so

```
<input ... typeaheadMinLength="0">
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm listing it using remote data. my settings is already set to 0 and it still doesn't fire on focus

Comment: Does it not show because it's loading? Maybe pre-load it?